# How to add scroll bar to the custom form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm developing a custom form that provides more options to customize the appearance of the form.

For that I have derived the class from System.Windows.Forms.Form class and overridden the WndProc(ref Message m) method.

I have processed the required window messages (WM_NCPAINT, WM_NCCALCSIZE, etc) to customize the form.

I have set **AutoScroll** property to true.

Microsoft form displays a scrollbar automatically, when the size of the control placed in the form is larger than the size of the form.

But my custom form doesn't display any scrollbar in such case.

I have handled the window message WM_NCCALCSIZE to specify the client area size of my form as given below.

```
 void On_WM_NcCalcSize(ref Message m)
 {
    rect.Top += borderThickness + titleBarHeight;
    rect.Left += borderThickness;
    rect.Right -= borderThickness;
    rect.Bottom -= borderThickness;
    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.LParam, true);
 }
```

Can you please confirm whether this is the reason?

I have another doubt.

I don't know whether it will affect the Controls.Count value if I add the scrollbar by myself.

If yes, then what should I do to display scrollbar on the form without adding it by myself?

Whether I have to draw the scrollbar in the non client area of the form?

Kindly provide your valuable solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mohanram Anbukkarasu.

Comment: as you have made a custom form, you would have to create your own function to `show scrollbar`, along with `its appearance` and deal with its `scroll events`

Comment: Use ILSPY or Reflector and see the implementation you're missing - perhaps it's a sealed class. I'm surprised deriving from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` doesn't do this automatically. Some code and screenshots to reproduce the problem would be great, please [edit]

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more details. Please check this now.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you derive from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` the scrollbars will appear automatically. So maybe you mess something up in your overriden `WndProc` method. Also note that the properties `Dock` and `Anchor` of the child controls will influence the behavior of `AutoScroll`. You may also consider to add an additional `Panel` inside your form where you add the controls. You can then control the scrolling of this panel.